# Livesearch - javascript clickable row

Tags: jquery

I am still working on my live search function. It populates perfectly, but now I want to add the clickable row function, which works by itself but not when I integrate it with the other code.

http://www.fpmnky.com/
This is without the clickable code

http://www.fpmnky.com/index2.php
The live search doesn't work after I add the extra code for the clickable row.
This is with the code below:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.watermark.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">


  $(document).ready(function() {

  $("#airport").watermark("");

  $("#airport").keyup(function()
  {
  var airport = $(this).val();
  var dataString = 'keyword='+ airport;
  if(airport.length>1)

  {
  $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "ajax-search.php",
  data: dataString,
  beforeSend:  function() {

  $('input#airport').addClass('loading');

  },
  success: function(server_response)
  {

  $('#searchresultdata').html(server_response).show();
  $('span#faq_category_title').html(airport);

  if ($('input#airport').hasClass("loading")) {
   $("input#airport").removeClass("loading");
    } 

  }
  });
  }return false;
  });
  });

  jQuery( function($) {
$('tr[href]').addClass('clickable').click( function() {
    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
}).find('a').hover( function() {
    $(this).parents('tr').unbind('click');
}, function() {
    $(this).parents('tr').click( function() {
        window.location = $(this).attr('href');
    });
});

$('tr[href]').css( 'cursor', 'pointer' );    
$('tr[href]').hover(function() {
$(this).css('cursor','pointer');
});
  }); 

  </script>
```

I am guessing it is a formatting issue, I am still new to javascript/jQuery, so help me out here.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have an error on line 50.

```
$("#airport").watermark("");
```

This watermark function seems to cause a problem. Use Firefox and press strg+shift+k to see the error. On the first page, you don't have this error message. Because of this problem I think tat not all the JS is executed, and I think that's your problem.